# App running slow when installed via MDM server compared to AppStore

Tags: ios, mdm

So we have a *white-labeled* apps, and one of our client distributes their app through MDM server instead of the Apple's AppStore.

For some reason this client reported that the app is "slow/freeze" when open, he provided some videos that show the issue and the app is indeed "slow/freeze" in the videos. But when we let them install the app through AppStore the app runs properly without the "slow/freeze" issue.

Is there a difference when the app installed via MDM vs AppStore? Should the app performance get affected/reduced if installed with MDM server? If MDM server weren't setup properly can possible cause this?

As of now we don't have access to the client's MDM server does we can't investigate if the issue is on their MDM server setup.

Comment: Is it a B2B app distributed through AppStore Connect?  If so then there should be no difference; it is a standard App Store build and signed the same way as a normal App Store app. I would check that they haven't implemented a VPN on the device for managed apps

Comment: @Paulw11, We only gave them an IPA file signed by AppStore provision. We also upload the same IPA to Apple's AppStore and send them an exact copy.